# Stuck in ubuntu during booting. It says "you are in emergency mode" and nothing is working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I started my laptop booted into ubuntu then it shows

```
You are in emergency mode.After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs,"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
```

I entered `exit` to boot into default mode but it again coming back to same window after checking my disk to 50%.

Here are steps that i followed

1. `sudo -i`
2. `cd /`
3. `ls`
4. `cd etc`
5. `ls`

The outputs I get from commands is shown as follows:
[ubuntu output of above codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHvgw.jpg)

6. `blkid`
7. `here type command that you used to edit fstab`
8. `cat fstab`
9. `sudo nano fstab`
10. `cat fstab`

Outputs I got from commands above are as follows:

[output of command blkid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrLvD.jpg)

[output of command sudo nano fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qAZR.jpg)

[output of command cat fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbuOQ.jpg)

I am operating ubuntu in dual boot with windows.

I am currently new to ubuntu family but i got stuck. Anyone having any advice to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you do what it said? "After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs," What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It is `20.04` lts version of ubuntu

Comment: Check out https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/